# Some npm modules are undefined, when used in client-side Meteor scripts

Tags: meteor, npm, ecmascript-6

I have a Meteor 1.3 project and use some client-side libraries, installed via npm.

For example, I use Matter.js, that is installed this way

```
npm install --save matter-js
```

and used this way (CoffeScript):

```
{Matter, Engine, World, Body, Bodies, Composite, Composites, Svg, Events, Common, Vector} = require 'matter-js'
```

All imported symbols are available in code it everything is fine.

But, when I trying to install 'autosize' library:

```
npm install --save autosize
```

and use it in code (CoffeScript):

```
{autosize} = require 'autosize'
```

I get

> TypeError: autosize is not a function

Maybe, I'm doing something wrong?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!

autosize library exports its autosize function using

```
export default autosize;
```

So, it should be imported this way, without curly braces (CoffeeScript):

autosize = require 'autosize'

Now autosize function is available!

I hope, it will be useful for someone.

Thanks!